# Не запускается genymotion

Tags: ubuntu, genymotion

Не запускается genymotion, пишет

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.
>
> Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.

Где то писали что мб кирилица в пути,но проверил нету вроде
ставил на убунту 14.04

Comment: sudo service vboxdrv setup делал?

Comment: нет.попробую сделать